# How to Add Contacts from Gmail to Infusionsoft using PHP?

Tags: php, gmail

I need to create a new contact in Infusionsoft for each new email received in a GMail account.  I've setup the following to do the API call to Infusionsoft:

```
public function addCon($cMap, $optReason = "") {

    $carray = array(
            php_xmlrpc_encode($this->key),
            php_xmlrpc_encode($cMap,array('auto_dates')));
    $conID = $this->methodCaller("ContactService.add",$carray);
    if (!empty($cMap['Email'])) {
        if ($optReason == "") { $this->optIn($cMap['Email']); } else { $this->optIn($cMap['Email'],$optReason); }
    }
    return $conID;
}
```

How do I query GMail for a list of email addresses, and names, and insert those into my InfusionSoft contact records using PHP?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not using the PHP SDK from infusionsoft? It will make creating contacts easier in Infusionsoft.
http://developers.infusionsoft.com/devkits/iSDK.zip

As for pulling emails from gmail try this:
http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap